# Is it possible to set up declarative control binding in the codebehind?

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET WebForms, you can be all like:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="mylabel" Text='<%#Eval("myvalue") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

This declarative binding gets the value from the proper column/member in the datasource.  Is it possible to do this in the codebehind:

```
mylabel.Text = String.Format("<%# Eval(""{0}"") %>", ControlName)
```

Edit:  inb4 *have you tried it?*  Yes.  I will add that there's some parsing somewhere that actually prevents that string from showing when my grid binds, so I know I am touching onto something here.

Comment: Are you trying to create a template from code-behind?

Comment: @NikitaSilverstruk Yes.  I've created a custom ItemTemplate and EditItemTemplate using the ITemplate interface I have it working.  The only ugly part about it is finding the control in the template when I don't know whether or not the template will even be there (it's a GridView that's used to edit any table in the database, so you never know what types of columns will be there).  If I could have it be self-binding, it would find itself and I wouldn't have to do anything.

Comment: Show some code, please. I've done something like this already. The gridview is built based on the object type returned... Take a look at this thread, maybe it will give you an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15912247/791952